# Accessing csv file placed in hdfs using spark

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have placed a csv file into the hdfs filesystem using `hadoop -put` command. I now need to access the csv file using [pyspark csv](https://github.com/seahboonsiew/pyspark-csv). Its format is something like

```
`plaintext_rdd = sc.textFile('hdfs://x.x.x.x/blah.csv')`
```

I am a newbie to hdfs. How do I find the address to be placed in `hdfs://x.x.x.x`?

Here's the output when I entered

`hduser@remus:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /input`

```
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup        158 2015-06-12 14:13 /input/test.csv
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide the full path of your files in HDFS and the url will be mentioned in your hadoop configuration core-site or hdfs-site where you mentioned.

> Check your core-site.xml & hdfs-site.xml for get the details about
>   url.

Easy way to find any url is access your hdfs from your browser and get the path.

```
If you are using absolute path in your file system use file:///<your path>
```

Comment: I access hadoop in my browser with `http://localhost:50070/explorer.html#/input` . So, in this case, what should I enter?

Comment: u should - http://localhost:50070/input/test.csv , check this entire path in ur explorer, it must be available there

Comment: I found it in the core-site.xml as mentioned in your answer. (It was in the /etc folder in the directory where hadoop is installed). So, hdfs://user:54310

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify absolute path without hdfs://

```
plaintext_rdd = sc.textFile('/input/test.csv')
```

Spark while running on the same cluster with HDFS use hdfs:// as default FS.

Answer (score 0):

Start the spark shell or the spark-submit by pointing to the package which can read csv files, like below:

```
spark-shell  --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0
```

And in the spark code, you can read the csv file as below:

```
val data_df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
              .option("header", "true")
              .schema(<pass schema if required>)
              .load(<location in HDFS/S3>)
```